# Can you strip a mips64 object file?

Tags: static-analysis, mips

-strip doesn’t know what this file is but read elf and objdump recognize it read elf gives entry and all the headers. I’m trying to find main() or the start function. Can I strip the file? Do I need to? Using ghidra as well and searching for it reveals nothing so maybe it’s hidden? Entry is  0x0

Comment: Why do you think you need to *strip* it to analyze? Stripping actually removes information that could make it easier!

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Basically a bunch of people said it makes it easier that is the only reason. How should I be going about finding main()